# legend and fieldset in android

Tags: android, legend, fieldset

I want to know if it's possible in android to do a form like that :

[image]

At this moment, I made a shape to produce the border (I use this shape as a background of my linearlayout, but i don't know how to deal with the text).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I have managed to get a frame with title using the following technique.

1. Use `FrameLayout` for the overall layout.
2. Inside add another layout for your main content - this can be anything.  For the background of this layout, use a custom XML drawable with `stroke` to draw the frame.  Make sure to add margins in this layout, especially `marginTop`, as you need some room to display the title of the frame. Also add some padding to make it look nicer.
3. Use `TextView` with opaque background and some paddings as the title.  Set `marginLeft` on it to a reasonable value to offset the title from the left.

Here's my XML for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <!--  This is the main content -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" android:background="@drawable/frame"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="20dp">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Main Content" android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--  This is the title label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white" android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Testing"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When executed, I get this on the app:

[image]

Feel free to tweak the margins/paddings to align the title the way you need.

Comment: I don't think it will work the same on different screen densities.

Comment: @AdilMalik As long as you use `dp` units everywhere, it will.

Comment: I just tried your code. There was a little difference in `ldpi` and `mdpi` devices.

Comment: Frankly, I don't think anybody cares about ldpi any more :) I had tested it in mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi - and it worked fine.

Comment: For those like me, and didn't realise what should be in drawable/frame, here is my frame: <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"><stroke android:width="1px" android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" /><padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" /></shape>

Comment: What's `@drawable/frame`? is it the border line?

Comment: @Phlip Yes, it is.  Look at the comment just above yours - it has the details.

Comment: That RelativeLayout makes the Code Analyzer ("lint") barf: "This 'LinearLayout' layout or its 'RelativeLayout' parent is useless; transfer the 'background' attribute to the other view." I don't care if it works...

Comment: @Phlip there is no LinearLayout in my answer.

Comment: and when I take mine out the form collapses. Guess I gotta silence the linter...