# Android add text in background border image

Tags: android

[image: how to put text in border]

How can i add text over the border in android

Some think like this
[Text in Border CSS HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731310/text-in-border-css-html)

Comment: that is a text view on top of some other view/ Nothing special/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [legend and fieldset in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155353/legend-and-fieldset-in-android)

Comment: You can use WebView to achieve this task

Comment: Try RelativeLayout with Textview.

Comment: take relativelayout, set background with some border width. and add textview to the top-left of layout with margin-left around 20dp

Comment: But text over border is hided. Not overlapped

Comment: the gaps on left and right of "AAA" and border , you will get by setting paddingLeft and paddingRight to textView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also achieve this in non ethical way..its quite a shortcut way to  implement this....Try this...

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="hia" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="vvvv"
        android:textSize="24dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this layout inside the layout copied from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155353/legend-and-fieldset-in-android)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white" android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Testing"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/frame"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Main Content" android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

create a `frame.xml` inside drawable

```
<shape xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<stroke android:width="1px" android:color="@color/black" /><padding android:left="1dp" 
android:top="1dp" 
android:right="1dp" 
android:bottom="1dp" />
</shape>
```