# How to create customized text input layout like attached design.?

Tags: android, android-layout, xml-drawable

I tried many custom drawing and I don't have idea about this design.Anyone help me out to do this design on drawable or any other way.

[image]

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
<stroke
    android:color="@color/black"
    android:width="2dp"/>
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
<corners
    android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
```

Comment: Share code snippet you have tried

Comment: do you have any kind of image exactly you want to implement?

Comment: @AnandPhadke https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHF6S.png

Comment: instead writting code in comment please edit  your question!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155353/legend-and-fieldset-in-android get an idea from this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can  setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) when you checks the credentials  on the exception of your try catch, assuming that you're doing the check that way. And if isn't an error you just let the objecet as (View.GONE) or (View.INVISIBLE)

Comment: I need a help to design this type of layout @joa

Comment: you can create a drawable resource with your custom error img and then set it as the background of your layout programatically in the event @raj

Comment: Do you have any idea about to create drawable like this design