# Is it possible to replace existing textView with new dynamic textView programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I need to replace textview which is already define in xml layout file with dynamic textview created programmatically in my Activity class file.

Comment: [mcve] perhaps?

Comment: Why do you want to replace a `textView`? Please elaborate.

Comment: why do you want to replace the TextView? Why not replace the text or any of its properties instead?

Comment: @Udit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51190630/how-to-create-customized-text-input-layout-like-attached-design/51191166?noredirect=1#comment89366398_51191166 i need to make a design like this,I try to combine image and text in a single drawable but i can't able to do that,so i try to replace textview with my custom textview.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need replace it, just get the particular properties from `textView` (from Java) and set them on `text_view` (from XML).

For example:

```
text_view.setText(textView.getText().toString())
text_view.setColor(textView.getColor())
...
text_view.setAnything(textView.getAnything())
```

Maybe it helpfull to you

Comment: What is `setAnything`? :D

Comment: @tahsinRupam It assigns something to something. :)

Comment: @Rohit5k2 But then you have to use `setSomething()`, right?

Comment: Guys can you help me out to design this layout  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51190630/how-to-create-customized-text-input-layout-like-attached-design/51191166?noredirect=1#comment89366398_51191166

Comment: I'm go try simule a result for you. Wait few minutes. Android Studio is openig...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get why you would do this, but anyhow will layout the steps:

1. get reference to the TextView containing ViewGroup
2. call removeView with TextView Reference.
3. call addView with new TextView.

   TextView old = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.old_text_view)
   LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container)
   TextView new = new TextView()

   layout.removeView(old);
   layout.addView(new, position);